# dotnet grpc is failing to run - exception created

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, grpc

I am using VS2019 net5.0 with Grpc.AspNetCore v2.34.0. When I run dotnet grpc add-file - or indeed other commands like list I get an exception, which I think is saying it can't find the csproj file. (Its being run in the same directory)  I have tried:

- The same thing with the basic generated Greeter grpc project with the
  same results.
- Also tried with a project that used to work fine.
- Specifiying the full path to the project file with the -p flag
- Looked for global.json in case that was clashing - no global.json

No doubt I am missing something obvious - any ideas?

```
PS C:\Users\tim\source\repos\GRPCTemplate> dotnet grpc add-file 'Protos/greet.proto'
```

Unhandled exception: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK resolver type "WorkloadSdkResolver" failed to load. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Users\tim\source\repos\GRPCTemplate\GRPCTemplate.csproj
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadMSBuildSdkResolver.WorkloadSdkResolver..ctor()

dotnet --info

```
 OS Platform: Windows
```

RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 5.0.1
Commit:  b02e13abab

.NET SDKs installed:
5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: You can refer to the  [link](https://github.com/dotnet/tye/issues/699),it may be caused by version.

Comment: Feels like this might be correct - but have no idea where to go to fix it.

Comment: In the link,you can see what jkotalik said.